# Nuxt generates real-time dynamic routing from the API

Tags: nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

I need to implement a [URL-key](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-urls.html#url-key) requirement similar to Magento, changing the URL address in real time according to the background to access.

Take a dynamic URL with parameters

```
http://mystore.com/detail?id=135
```

Become Static URL as follows

```
http://mystore.com/racer-tank.html
```

Write an example, already implemented this function, but need to optimize performance, any good suggestions

Example online at https://od2c7.sse.codesandbox.io/

**EDIT:**

I have created a minimal example, where the data generation might be partially repetitive, but it works without problems... https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-dynamic-routing-od2c7

I will update the question when I find the solution to my problem.